# What kind of vent material can be used for gas dryer?

Tags: gas, appliances, exhaust-vent

Dryer at present butts up to vent sticking into the room.  This works just fine.

I want to put the dryer and washer on a plinth to make it easier to access.  I don't want to put the dryer further out into the room.

The plinth will put the dryer 7" up.  How do I route the vent?  What specs do I ask for?

I know that the aluminum foil light weight flex tube is a bad idea.

There is a type of flex tube available, but it's not clear if it's suitable for gas dryers, nor is it clear if it can be cut to a shorter length.  (All the ones I've found are 6 feet.  I think I need between 2 and 3 feet.

Comment: *plinth* - great word! (I used it once as word-of-the-day in Toastmasters and it didn't go over so well.) What kind of ductwork do you have right now? Picture maybe?

Answer (score 2):

The best choice is metal hard wall duct. 
[image]
It is smooth inside and does not cause lint to build up.

Lint build up can be a bit of a fire hazard and leads to restriction of air flow that is exhausting moisture. That leads to extended drying times.

If you must use flex get the semi rigid type and be careful not to crush the shape when making turns. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Because of the mount points, the minimum will be a 360 single turn spiral.  This would require 4 of the 90 degree adjustable bends.  Is ordinary heating duct metal piping sufficient?  E.g. https://www.homedepot.ca/product/imperial-4-inch-x-90-degree-adjustable-elbow-30-gauge/1000107349

Comment: Yes ordinary metal duct work is good

Comment: Just a word to the wise, every area has their own code on what you can and cannot do, but most allow you to leverage the dryer manufacturer specification as king (which are usually very ... relaxed ... in contrast). So look at your dryer paperwork and see if you do not exceed its max run. 1 90 degree turn is = 5' if I recall correctly, so you are eating 20' of run right there.